# How to send an email containing .csv file of one sheet within a workbook once a checkbox is True

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, email-attachments

Let me start by saying I've never run any scripts within google sheets, and I am not familiar with Code, though I think that will be part of my solution here.

I have a lengthy workbook that contains an order form for several days of the month on individual tabs and then all those tabs funnel to a summary tab at the end that orders are placed from.

What I need to figure out is how to get notification emails sent when a checkbox *from any tab* is marked "true". BONUS POINTS if we can have the email contain the CSV of the order tab within the workbook.

Here is a sample workbook with a much more parsed down version of what I am working with:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UhsupUoLT3l4Heq2c1pWUmwxX1cHuV0WzWNUwiB3Yo0/edit?usp=sharing

I've looked and looked and I can see that there are options on how to to do this within scripts, but not having ever used this I'm unsure what I would need to copy and what I would need to adjust to match my own workbook (if that makes sense). If someone can copy what I'd need to put into scripts and then maybe **BOLD** what I'd need to input myself that would be immensely helpful!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and [edit] your question to include a [mre] showing what you have completed so far.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be a starting point:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();//active sheet
  const shts = e.source.getSheet();//all sheets in the spreadsheet
  const excl = ["Sheet1","Sheet2"];//Sheets to exclude
  const chkboxColumn = 4;//Check box column
  const idx = shts.filter(s => !~excl.indexOf(s.getName())).map(s => sh.getName()).indexOf(sh.getName());
  if(~idx && e.range.columnStart == chkboxColumn && e.value == "TRUE") {
    let msg = `SheetName: ${sh.getName()} Row: ${e.range.rowStart}`;
    MailApp.sendEmail("recipient email","Subject",msg)
  }
}
```

You will need to create an installable  onEdit trigger.